# link from SQlit to GSheet ? Or GAS to import the data?

Tags: sqlite, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to read or import updated data from a SQlite table to GSheet.
Indeed, I'd like to build pivot table from data which are initialy located in a table from a SQlite DataBase.

Do you have some way to build the "connexion" or the "direct access" ?
Or it's needed to use other script language like Microsoft PowerShell, Python etc...

Comment: Have you tried [JDBC](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc)?

Comment: Is your sqlite database on a LAMP server or similar (running php) ? If so you could possibly use UrlFetch to make SELECT calls to your db. Here is a demo example for setting up the server (written for App Inventor but the idea is the same) https://ai2.metricrat.co.uk/guides/howto-php-sqlite3-with-ai2. And a link to the source for this: https://zetcode.com/php/sqlite3/

Comment: Sorry we are not on a LAMP servor or WAMP or similar. We have SQlite database on local folder (desktop).

Comment: I don't tried JDBC but as I don't see anything on SQlite on the page, I'm not sure that it is the right "connector"

Comment: After my investigations, JDBC doesn't work for "SQlite" databases even if I replace "mysql" by "sqlite". If you have other idea to explore, I am still interested.